# Detect current database is partial restored

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql

I have a database backup file when I need to start up the application I want to show a warning if the database is partial restored.

How can I detect/recognize in C# that the current database is restored with full or partial mode.

Comment: What do you mean by "*partial restored*"?

Comment: Simple Recovery Model the database without the streaming files. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190388.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way to solve the problem thanks for all help!

```
var restoreType = dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<string>(@"Select restore_type FROM [msdb].[dbo].[restorehistory]").FirstOrDefault<string>();
```

In this way I will retrive the database restore type: 
   - If restoreType = "D" than database is full restored!
   - Else if "F" than I know that the database is  partial restored!

This DbContext from EF if you are using another kind of connection you can just use the T-Sql statement.

Answer (score 1):

user will not be able to connect to the DB if the DB is is not AccessReady/ONLINE.
the oroginal connection you make to the Database server make sure you connect to the one of the system DB. Master/MSDB/TEMPDB etc... after that you will need a stored procedure installed in one of this system DB that you can call from Application repetedly lets say every 5 second that gives you the resut if your DB is reday to access or not.
your procedure will need this simple query

IF EXISTS(  SELECT TOP 1 1 
        FROM sys.databases 
        WHERE name= 'your DB name' 
        AND state_desc = 'Online'
    )

```
SELECT 'DB is ready to Access'
```

ELSE
    SELECT 'DB is not ready to Access'

Comment: Yes but I have the use case the user can connect to the database. he just have partially restored the database without to delete the old one so he have all the data but i need in this case to show the warning also thanks

Comment: Well I am not aware of all possibilities where you can put this code but you got the point. whenever you are expecting user to receive the warning message you need to find a safe place in your code where you can make such call to detect if DATABASE is actually ready. You can also trigger this call based on the error you got from first failure.